# I want to change layout background in another Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, preferencefragment

My app consists of multiple layouts and the layout ends with a finish() to avoid unnecessary reconnection when the back button is touched when switching layouts.

That's why I have an issue where the app reinitializes when turning off or switching the layout even if I change the value of a layout element like setText or setBackgorundColor.

So I would like to keep the theme selected by the user so that it can be used in a PreferenceFragment activity that has changed its value and saved even after exiting the app.

The problem is that in this PreferencFragment java class file I tried to change the values ​​of multiple layouts (setText or setBackground... something more), but nothing works.

Even if I use LayouInflater to get an element from another layout and set the setting to setText, the setting change does not take effect when exiting the PreferencesFragment window.

****SettingFragment.java****

```
    public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);

            if(key.equals("theme")){
                String datas = pref.getString("theme", null);
                if(datas.equals("RED")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // Nothing To change !!
                }
                else if(datas.equals("BLUE")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BLUE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(datas.equals("GREEN")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GREEN!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: here I can see that you have used  view.setBackgroundColor only once not in other conditions so your code maybe not correct

Comment: @PJain 
So.. is there another options? or Solutions? I really need to help..

Comment: firstly if you want to change the theme you need to re-inflate the view or else you can say like you need to recreate the view and as per your code put view.setBackgroundColor also for blue and green conditions and check it again